# Checking a text File containing only a single 0 value

Tags: powershell

I have a Move Item Script which I only want to execute if there is not just a single 0 in the file. I have thought about checking the file size for 0kb\empty but because of the value in there the file size is 1kb.

Code tried:

```
$file = Get-Content "transfer\A28AP.txt"
$containsWord = $file | %{$_ -match "0"}
if ($containsWord -contains $true) {
   Move-Item "transfer\A28AP.txt" -Destination "transfer\A28History\"
}
```

Comment: If it truly is just a `0` (new line chars excluded), the appropriate match is `^0$`. You should use the `-Raw` switch on `Get-Content` so that you do one match per file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code by just using `-match` inside your if. I also corrected the regex:

```
$file = Get-Content "transfer\A28AP.txt" -raw
if ($file -notmatch '^0$') {
   Move-Item "transfer\A28AP.txt" -Destination "transfer\A28History\"
}
```

Comment: I have this script Rename-Item "History\A50AP.txt" $_.FullName -NewName "$($_.DirectoryName)\$($_.BaseName)_$(Get-Date -F yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm)$($_.Extension)"  however I am receiving an error, how can I rewrite this? I Want the date and time to appear in the File name after A50AP

Comment: Please start a new Question, this could be useful for someone else too.